# Derivation log function with e

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

$f(g)=log(e^g-1+d)$ where $d$ is constant.

$f'(g)=\frac {e^g} {e^g-1+d} \approx \frac{(1+g)}{(g+d)}$

How can I derive the last one?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! I'd recommend formatting your math with LaTeX syntax (see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community : unclear only because mathjax not being used.  Once the OP edits his question with mathjax, I request that you then withdraw your comment.

Comment: @user2661923 You seem to regard Community as a human being capable of "withdrawing" comments. That is not true.

Comment: @Trebor true, but if more mathSE reviewers respond as I do, some positive step will eventually be taken to resolve the misbehavior of the Community bot.

Comment: $f'(g)=\frac {e^g} {e^g-1+d}.$

Comment: @guest . Consider upvoting answers which were useful.

Comment: Interestingly, the approximation has the wrong concavity, so that a linear approximation is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I think you want to ask a two part question. First
$f'(g)=\frac{e^{g}}{e^{g}-1+d}$ this just follows from chain rule.

Now I think what you want to ask is how does this approximate to the given expression.

For that you need the maclaurin expansion of $e^{x}$ about $0$.

$e^{x}=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+...$

So if you consider only the first two terms and neglect higher order terms.

You can say $e^{x}\approx = 1+x$ when $x$ is very very small.

Using that you can write it as $\approx \frac{1+g}{g+d}$.

Does this answer your question?